# OpenCV mat of mats

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the best way to represent with OpenCV(C++) a mat of mats? At the moment in my code, I use a vector of `vector<Mat>` and I need the benefits of using a matrix.

Comment: isn't it just a bigger matrix? if you have nxm matrices of size oxp, then you have a bigger matrix of size (n * o)x(m * p)

Comment: What do you hope to gain in using a matrix of matrices? Can you provide more details on your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limited to my searches, unfortunately such thing is not defined in Opencv-C++ (python version has it though). vector is all you can get.

Although if all of your images are grayscale and have the same size, you can define an n-channel image and put each of your images into one of the channels, for example:

```
Mat im1 = Mat::ones(n_row , n_col , CV_8UC1);
Mat im2 = Mat::ones(n_row , n_col , CV_8UC1);
Mat im3 = Mat::ones(n_row , n_col , CV_8UC1);
... // n similar images...

Mat img(n_row , n_col , CV_8UC(n));

vector<Mat> vec;

vec.push_back(im1);
vec.push_back(im2);
vec.push_back(im3);
... // push back all the n images

merge(vec,img);
```